# Proving an equality on the derivative of given polynomials

Tags: polynomials, linear-transformations

I found this question

> Prove that for all $n\in \Bbb N_0$ there exists a unique polynomial $Q_p\in \Bbb Q[x]$ such that
>   $$\left\{\begin{array}{l}Q_p(x+1)-Q_p(x)=x^p\quad (\star)\\ Q_p(0)=0\end{array}\right.$$
>   and that we have
>   $$Q'_p(x)-Q'_p(0)=pQ_{p-1}(x),\quad \forall p\in \Bbb N$$

Well, for the first part of the question, I defined the linear transformation $\varphi$ on the linear space $\Bbb Q[x]$ defined by: $\varphi(Q)=Q(x+1)-Q(x)$. I proved that $\ker\varphi=\Bbb Q_0[x]$ i.e. the constant polynomials and that $\operatorname{Im}\varphi=\Bbb Q[x]$ so that for $x^p$ there is $Q_p$ such that $\varphi(Q_p+c)=x^p$ for all constant $c\in \Bbb Q$. Now we choose $c=-Q_p(0)$ to satisfy the requirement $Q_p(0)=0$ hence the uniqueness. Now I'm stuck in the second part of the question. I tried to differentiate the equality $(\star)$ and to replace $px^{p-1}$ by $p(Q_{p-1}(x+1)-Q_{p-1}(x))$ but I can't progress further. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is ok.

For the second one, differentiate as you did : you have
$$Q_p'(x) = Q_p'(x+1)-px^{p-1} = Q_p'(x+1)-p(Q_{p-1}(x+1)-Q_{p-1}(x))$$ $$= Q_p'(x+1) - pQ_{p-1}(x+1) + pQ_{p-1}(x) $$

So you get that for each $x$,
$$Q_p'(x) -  pQ_{p-1}(x)= Q_p'(x+1) - pQ_{p-1}(x+1)  $$

This shows that the polynomial $Q'_p - pQ_{p-1}$ is constant. Evaluating in $0$ shows that its value is equal to $Q_p'(0)$.

Comment: I was on the right way but I didn't see this idea. Thanks!